# Would CPU continue executing the next line code when the GPU kernel is running? Would it cause an error?

Tags: cuda

I am reading the book "CUDA by example" by Sanders, where the author mentioned that p.441: For example, when we launched the kernel in our ray tracer, the GPU begins executing our code, but the CPU continues executing the next line of our program before the GPU finishes. -- Highlighted mar 4, 2014

I am wondering if this statement is correct. For example, what if the next instruction CPU continues executing depends on the variables that the GPU kernel outputs? Would it cause an error? From my experience, it does not cause an error. So what does the author really mean?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the author is correct.  Suppose my kernel launch looks like this:

```
int *h_in_data, *d_in_data, *h_out_data, *d_out_data;
// code to allocate host and device pointers, and initialize host data
...
// copy host data to device
cudaMemcpy(d_in_data, h_in_data, size_of_data, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
mykernel<<<grid, block>>>(d_in_data, d_out_data);
// some other host code happens here
// at this point, h_out_data does not point to valid data
...
cudaMemcpy(h_out_data, d_out_data, size_of_data, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
//h_out_data now points to valid data
```

Immediately after the kernel launch, the CPU continues executing host code.  But the data generated by the device (either `d_out_data` or `h_out_data`) is not ready yet.  If the host code attempts to use whatever is pointed to by `h_out_data`, it will just be garbage data.  This data only becomes valid after the 2nd `cudaMemcpy` operation.

Note that using the data (`h_out_data`) before the 2nd `cudaMemcpy` will not generate an error, if by that you mean a segmentation fault or some other run time error.  But any results generated will not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My follow-up question is that what if I swap the pointers ( d_in_data and d_out_data ) after mykernel<<<...>>>(d_in_data, d_out_data) by the simple instruction like this: temp=d_out_data; d_out_data=d_in_data; d_in_data=temp; These are CPU instructions. Would they mess up the computations on GPUs, since my kernel may still not finished yet, but CPU continues executing these code lines? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pointers (in my example, `d_in_data`, `d_out_data`) are  passed to the device by *value*, just like regular C API usage would indicate. (The data they reference is passed by *pointer*, but the pointer itself is passed by *value*).  Therefore modifying the pointer values after they have been sent to the kernel call has no effect on kernel behavior.  C function parameters passed by value have their own copy of that value that is local to (within) the function, independent of the calling environment.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel launches in CUDA are by default asynchronous, i.e., the control will return to CPU after the launch. Now if the next instruction of the CPU is another kernel launch, then you don't need to worry, this launch will be done only after the previously launched kernel has finished its execution.
However, if the next instruction is some CPU instruction only which is accessing the results of the kernel, there can be a problem of accessing garbage value. Therefore, excessive care has to be taken and device synchronization should be done as and when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My follow-up question is that what if I swap the pointers ( d_in_data and d_out_data ) after mykernel<<<...>>>(d_in_data, d_out_data) by the simple instruction like this: temp=d_out_data; d_out_data=d_in_data; d_in_data=temp; These are CPU instructions. Would they mess up the computations on GPUs, since my kernel may still not finished yet, but CPU continues executing these code lines? Thanks in advance!